# JavaScript regex replace '+ve' with 'positive' not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have what seems a very simple task - find all occurrences of '+ve' in a string and replace with 'positive'.

I know I need to escape the plus symbol, hence I'm using '\\+'.

It works fine if I don't combine with word boundaries:

```
var txt = 'I am most +ve this should work!';
var pattern = new RegExp('\\+ve', 'gi');
alert(txt.replace(pattern, 'positive'));
```

However, as soon as I combine with word boundaries, the regex fails to match:

```
var txt = 'I am most +ve this should work!';
var pattern = new RegExp('\\b\\+ve\\b', 'gi');
alert(txt.replace(pattern, 'positive'));
```

I'm sure there's an obvious solution - any suggestions most welcome!

Comment: Yeh.. You' re escaping twice

Comment: The other problem is the `+` and `v` is considered a word boundary too because `+` isn't a normal word character

Comment: Thank you Matt - of course '+' is not a normal word character - doh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that \b is going to match between `+v` because `+` is not a word character.

Probably the easiest fix is to match whitespace surrounding `+ve` instead:

```js
var txt = 'I am most +ve this should work!';
var pattern = /(^|\s)\+ve(\s|$)/gi;
console.log(txt.replace(pattern, ' positive '));
```

`\b` is equivalent to `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)` which if you break it down matches:

`^\w` a word character at the start of the string

`\w$` a word character at the end of the string

`\W\w` a non-word character followed by a word character

`\w\W` a word character followed by a non-word character

A "word character" is equivalent to: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` which, you'll note, doesn't include `+`. So `+v` is a *non-word character followed by a word character*. In other words, it matches `\W\w`.

Technically, the space around `+ve` might not be a space (it could be a tab, for example) so to preserve the correct spacing, you could do something like (this is where javascripts lack of lookbehinds are really annoying):

```
var pattern = /(\s)\+ve(\s)/gi;
console.log(txt.replace(pattern, '$1postive$2'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Below code will not work as expected when we use more than one '+ve'. Please check the output,

```
var txt = 'I am most +ve this should work! +ve';
var pattern = /\s\+ve\s/gi;
console.log(txt.replace(pattern, ' positive '));
```

Here is the output as you can see that second hasn't been replaced by the term.

**Output**

I am most positive this should work! +ve

**Alternatively you can opt**

```js
var txt = 'I am most +ve this should work! +ve and +ve and many more +ve';
txt = txt.split("+ve").join("positive");
console.log(txt)
```

Comment: A good point, but the problem there isn't _more than one `+ve`_, it's the end of the string. It's fixed in my answer now